# Redirect 301 appending old URL with New URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a problem while redirecting a page whose URL was changed but I want old URL to be redirected to new. Here is `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contactus/$ http://example.com/contact-us/ [R=301,L]
```

Using mod_rewrite in the last line I am not getting redirected to new URL but when I use mod_alias(Redirect) rule I get redirected to new URL but Old URL gets appended to in it in this format.

```
https://example.com/contact-us/?/contactus/
```

I have searched Stack Overflow for solution to this problem and tried many similar scenarios but that didn't work.

Comment: When I edited in `example.com` I fixed one instance where the dot in your domain name was missing (like `examplecom`).  I think that was a typo from replacing the actual domain name and not the actual cause of your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this the given order.

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^contactus/$ /contact-us/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteEngine On` is not required multiple times in same .htaccess.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing the change.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^contactus/$ http://example.com/contact-us/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Your mod_rewrite external redirects (the last three rules) are in the wrong place. These need to be *before* the internal rewrite (front-controller). By placing them at the end of the file they are never going to get processed for any URL other than static resources, since all other URLs are routed to `index.php`, at which point processing stops.

> when I use mod_alias(Redirect) rule I get redirected to new URL but Old URL gets appended

Different modules are processed independently regardless of the order of the directives in the config file. mod_alias is processed *after* mod_rewrite - but it is processed. However, the `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and everything after the match is appended onto the end of the target URL.

And there's no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directives

Have your directives like this:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^contactus/$ http://example.com/contact-us/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And make sure to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.